# How to get find if the input is empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my script everything works well except for the output for an empty input.

```
    <input id="id1" type="number" max="100" min="40">

    <button onclick="count()">OK</button>

    <p id="test"></p>

<script>    

var inpObj = document.getElementById('id1');

    function count() {
        if(inpObj.checkValidity() == false || inpObj.length === 0) {
            document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = inpObj.validationMessage;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "Input OK";
        }
    }

</script>
```

I have no idea why is this not working.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the value of `inpObj.checkValidity` and `inpObj.validationMessage` ? also what do you mean by it is not working? is there any error on browser console?

Comment: I'm following this tutorial, it is the javascript validation api part: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation_api.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
function count() {
        if(inpObj.checkValidity() == false ) {
            document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = inpObj.validationMessage;
        } else if(inpObj.value.length === 0) {
            document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "Empty"
        } else {
            document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "Input OK";
        }
    }
```

See : https://jsfiddle.net/Ldj170Lc/

Comment: It is working now, so `validationMessage` is not working for empty strings. You need to make an `else if` statement particularly for that usage. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

length is applied on string not on input object.
inpObj is HTML object(Input)

```
if(inpObj.checkValidity() == false || inpObj.value.length === 0) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `inpObj.value.length` instead of `inpObj.length` https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/g7e0bLjc/

```
var inpObj = document.getElementById('id1');

  function count() {
    if(inpObj.checkValidity() == false || inpObj.value.length === 0) {
      document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = inpObj.validationMessage;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "Input OK";
    }
  }
```

Comment: It works fine just try to paste a text on the input and the validationMessage will be outputted